# Having trouble while importing xmlaccess in Websphere Portal

Tags: websphere-portal

I am having trouble importing xmlaccess in Websphere Portal, giving some SSL exception error.

Could not connect to portal.
 An error occurred on the client: Could not establish SSL connection to portal. SSLHandshakeException occured.

Is there anyway I can import it through Portal administration console?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can import xmlaccess files through Portal Administration:

Administration > Portal Settings > Import XML

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already mentioned option within the Admin user interface you can define the key and trust store the xmlaccess client should use

```
xmlaccess.sh -user wpsadmin -password your_password -url https://portalhost:10035/wps/config/
             -in $PortalHome/doc/xml-samples/ExportAllUsers.xml -out result.xml
             -truststore $WASHome/profiles/wp_profile/etc/trust.p12 
             -trustpwd WebAS -trusttype PKCS12
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/adxmltsk_cmdln_sntx_ssl_elements.dita